# Obtain latitude and longitude using QAS API

Tags: java

I want to obtain latitude and longitude by postcode using QAS.

For instance, Google API has following instruction to do that:

```html
google.maps.Geocoder().geocode({
 "address": *postcode*
 }, function(res, stat) {
  if(stat === "OK"){
   var latitude = res[0].geometry.location.lat();
   var longitude = res[0].geometry.location.lng();
  } else {
      
 }
});
```

Is it possible to get coordinates of the postcode with QAS?
How?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to get the lat and long for several countries using the QAS API.

There are a couple of different ways you may be using the product, so I'll try and cover a range of possibilities.

If you are using '[Pro API](http://www.qas.co.uk/solutions/data-quality-software/data-capture/address-verification.htm)' or '[Pro Web](http://www.qas.co.uk/solutions/data-quality-software/data-capture/address-checker.htm)' and already have the data licensed to you, then if you open the Configuration editor (qacfgwn.exe) then you will be able to add latitude and longitude as "Dataplus" lines. These will the be returned along with the rest of your address and you can configure your application to take and use these as you need.

Else, if you are using one of our cloud solutions such as [Pro OnDemand](http://www.qas.co.uk/solutions/data-quality-software/data-capture/address-lookup-software.htm) then you you can log into the management portal and add them to your address in a similar way to above.

Whichever method you are currently using, if you do not see the lat / long then you might not have it associated with your account yet. If this is the case the contact you account manager or [our support team](http://support.qas.com/uk) who can help you out.